# Prestashop: how can i add tab in admin panel for my module when it installing?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

How can i add tab in admin panel for my module when it is installing?
Here is basic code for module http://dpaste.com/1PWGYHM

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this

```
$this->languages = Language::getLanguages();
//Admin Pdf Output
$tab = new Tab();
foreach ($this->languages as $lang)
    $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = 'Admin Pdf Output';
$tab->class_name = 'AdminPdfOutput';
$tab->id_parent = -1;
$tab->module = $this->name;
$tab->active = 1;
if (! $tab->add()) return false;
```

Then I create a file in `module_dir/controllers/admin/AdminPdfOutput.php` and declare it like this

```
class AdminPdfOutputController extends ModuleAdminController{
   ...
}
```